# How to remove the order of an ordered set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let  $ A = \{ a,b,(c,d),(e,f,g),((q,r),t)\}$. What is the notation for
$\{ a,b,\{c,d\},\{e,f,g\},\{\{q,r\},t\}\}$ ?   In other words, I want to remove all the ordering. I'd like notation that is extended to sets of any depth.

By the way,  $\cup \{a,b,(c,d)\} = \cup \{a,b,\{c,\{c,d\}\} \} = \{a,b,c,\{c,d\}\}$, which gives me the element $c$ that I don't want.  So a simple union won't work, right?

Comment: How do you figure that $\bigcup A=A$?

Comment: @Chris No one said $\{c,d\}$ is a member of $\cup A$. But $\cup A=A$ is not true here.

Comment: you are right.  I have done more education on $\cup A$.  I got a lot wrong.  However, my question still stands without that sentence gone.  I have  editted it.

Comment: There's no standard notation for this operation, but you could define it recursively.

Comment: It's weird to have a "type-dependent" operation like this, though (operating differently on tuples than on non-tuples). E.g. if $a$ happens to be a tuple, then your example is wrong. What are you using this for?

Comment: @Karl  I will add  a motivation to my question later today. Please check back tomorrow. Thanks.